# Redirect function is not working on the live server. But working on localhost

Tags: php

This is the function. This is working in the local host. But not working in the live server.

```
function redirect_to($location = NULL){
    if($location != NULL){
        header("Location: {$location}");
        exit;
    } 
}

if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){
    //success

    redirect_to("index.php");
}
```

Comment: redirect_to($location = NULL), why would you assign null to it there?!

Comment: It gives because initially its null. is that wrong?? but this is working on local host

Comment: what happens if you call the script on the live server? do you see a blank page? is redirect_to called? maybe $location parameter is null ?

Comment: And what's the return http status? Do you get the location header? Did you check your error log?

Comment: @Maerlyn : retun http status means??? can you clarify me bit more.

Comment: The http status returned by the server. 500 means an error, usually some syntax error. 200 means everything's ok. [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Status_codes).

Comment: There is no error code. Only a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define a default value for an argument and then check for it, just don't give it a default to begin with. Also remove the brackets in the `Location:` header.

```
function redirect_to($location){
    header("Location: $location");
    exit;
}

if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){
    //success

    redirect_to("index.php");
}
```